# Enzyme feature in databricks

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I am not able to get more information on this feature to understand what it actually solves. Are there documentation to understand what enzyme actually does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enzyme is work in progress and right now not so much public information about it. I think that the best one right now is this [blog post](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/06/29/delta-live-tables-announces-new-capabilities-and-performance-optimizations.html) that describes why it's created and what are the goals of the project.